# Uniform Convergence And Limits

Tags: real-analysis

Supoose that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on a set $E$ in a metric space. Let $x$ be a limit point of the set $E$. Suppose that $$\lim_{t \to x}f_n(t)=A_n$$, then $A_n$ converges and $$\lim_{n \to \infty}A_n = \lim_{t \to x}f(t)$$
$$$$I will use the fact that : If $f: A \to R$ be a function where $R$ is the set of real numbers and $c$ be a limit point of $A$ then we say that the $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)$$ exists if and only if for any given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that for all $x, y$ satisfying $d(x, c)<\delta$ and $d(y, c))<\delta$ we have $$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.$$
At first we prove that $$\lim_{t \to x}f(t)$$ exists. Supoose $\epsilon>0$ is given. Now for this $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ there exists a $N$ such that for any $n \geq N$, we have $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$, and hence $$|f_N(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$. Now as the $\lim_{t \to x}f_N(t)$ exists, so for $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ there eixts a $\delta$ such that whenever $d(s, x)<\delta$ and $d(t, x)<\delta$ we have $$|f_N(s)-f_N(t)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$. Now chose the same $\delta>0$ then again whenever $d(t, x)<\delta$ and $d(s, x)<\delta$ we have $$|f(s)-f(t)| \leq |f(s)-f_N(s)|+|f_N(s)-f_N(t)|+|f_N(t)-f(t)|<\epsilon$$, and hence the limit exists. Now we prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}A_n$$ exists. Now suppose $\epsilon>0$ is given then for $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ there exists a $N$ such that for any $n \geq N$ we have $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$. Now chose this $N$, then for any $n \geq N$, we have $$|\lim_{t \to x}f_n(t)-\lim_{ t \to x}f(t)| \leq |\lim_{t \to x}f_n(t)-f_n(s_n)|+|f_n(s_n)-f(s_n)|+|f(s_n)-\lim_{t \to x}f(t)|<\epsilon$$ because for every $n$, $s_n$ is chosen sufficiently close to $x$ such that $$|f_n(s_n)-\lim_{t \to x}f_n(t)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$ and $$|f(s_n)-\lim_{t \to x}f(t)<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$. And hence the conclusion follows.
$$$$Is My Proof Correct??